# Extracting ids out of arguments of different types

Tags: ruby, api

I'm building a Ruby API client. My brief is to extract ids out of various inputs and fetch the relevant data. It's working just fine at the moment but I think it's a little clumsy.

My specs (which pass):

```
shared_examples 'it requests ids' do |resource|
  it 'sends the ids to Foo::Client' do
    Foo.stub(:parse)
    Foo::Client.should_receive(resource).once.with(expected)
    Foo.send(resource, *args)
  end
end

describe Foo do
  describe 'resources have numeric ids only'
    [:accounts, :contacts].each do |resource|
      it_behaves_like 'it requests ids', resource do
        let(:args) { [1, 2] }
        let(:expected) { [1, 2] }
      end

      it_behaves_like 'it requests ids', resource do
        let(:args) { [3, 'jesse-pinkman', 5, {'links' => {resource.to_s => [98, 99]}}] }
        let(:expected) { [98, 99, 3, 5] }
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'resources have numeric and string ids'
    [:clients, :services].each do |resource|
      it_behaves_like 'it requests ids', resource do
        let(:args) { [2,'saul-goodman', 6] }
        let(:expected) { [2, 6, 'saul-goodman'] }
      end

      it_behaves_like 'it requests ids', resource do
        let(:args) { [3, 'saul-goodman', 5, {'links' => {resource.to_s => [202, 234]}}] }
        let(:expected) { [202, 234, 3, 5, 'saul-goodman'] }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And my code:

```
module Foo
  class << self
    [:accounts, :contacts, :clients, :services].each do |resource|
      define_method(resource) do |*args|
        ids = []
        unless args.empty?
          ids += hash_ids(args, resource)
          ids += numeric_ids(args)
          ids += text_ids(args) unless numeric_ids_only?(resource)
        end
        parse(client.send(resource, ids))
      end
    end

    private

    def hash_ids(args, resource)
      args.collect { |arg| arg['links'][resource.to_s] if arg.is_a? Hash }.compact!.flatten!.to_a
    end

    def numeric_ids(ids)
      ids.select { |id| !id.is_a?(Hash) && id.to_i > 0 }
    end

    def text_ids(ids)
      ids.select { |id| id.is_a? String }
    end

    def numeric_ids_only?(resource)
      [:accounts, :contacts].include?(resource)
    end

    def client
      Foo::Client
    end

    def parse(json)
      Foo::Adapter::JSON.parse(json)
    end
  end
end
```

My particular concern is the ugly concatenating of the `ids` array and passing all those `args` around. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

**You should expect**
Starting a couple of years back, `rspec` is moving to a [new expectation syntax](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax), you should consider porting to it:

```
shared_examples 'it requests ids' do |resource|
  it 'sends the ids to Foo::Client' do
    allow(Foo).to receive(:parse)

    expect(Foo::Client).to receive(resource).once.with(expected)

    Foo.send(resource, *args)
  end
end
```

**Be more transparent**
Your code hides pretty well the fact that `clients` and `services` is different from `accounts` and `contacts` - both in your code and in your tests.
It makes your code quite obfuscated (in the name of DRYness?) - you should make it clear that you have two different behaviors - and spell them out:

```
shared_examples 'resources have numeric ids only' do |resource|
  it_behaves_like 'it requests ids', resource do
    let(:args) { [1, 2] }
    let(:expected) { [1, 2] }
  end

  it_behaves_like 'it requests ids', resource do
    let(:args) { [3, 'jesse-pinkman', 5, {'links' => {resource.to_s => [98, 99]}}] }
    let(:expected) { [98, 99, 3, 5] }
  end
end

shared_examples 'resources have numeric and string ids' do |resource|
  it_behaves_like 'it requests ids', resource do
    let(:args) { [2,'saul-goodman', 6] }
    let(:expected) { [2, 6, 'saul-goodman'] }
  end

  it_behaves_like 'it requests ids', resource do
    let(:args) { [3, 'saul-goodman', 5, {'links' => {resource.to_s => [202, 234]}}] }
    let(:expected) { [202, 234, 3, 5, 'saul-goodman'] }
  end
end

it_behaves_like 'resources have numeric ids only', :accounts
it_behaves_like 'resources have numeric ids only', :contacts
it_behaves_like 'resources have numeric and string ids', :clients
it_behaves_like 'resources have numeric and string ids', :services
```

And in your code, I would rather use simple method delegation than meta-coding:

```
class << self
  def accounts(*args)
    parse(client.accounts(hash_ids(args, :accounts) + numeric_ids(args))
  end

  def contacts(*args)
    parse(client.accounts(hash_ids(args, :contacts) + numeric_ids(args))
  end

  def clients(*args)
    parse(client.accounts(hash_ids(args, :clients) + numeric_ids(args) + text_ids(args))
  end

  def services(*args)
    parse(client.accounts(hash_ids(args, :services) + numeric_ids(args) + text_ids(args))
  end
end
```

It might be less DRY, but it is a lot clearer what your class actually *does*.

Comment: Nice. I have refactored my specs to clarify the behaviour a little. I think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Rimian, the main suggestions I would make are two:

- loop through `args` just once; and
- use a case statement with argument `arg`, as it makes it easy to separate the `arg` objects by class.

Here is one way to apply these suggestions:

**Code**

```
require 'json'

module Foo
  class Client
    class << self
      [:accounts, :contacts, :clients, :services].each { |resource|
        define_method(resource) { |*args| process(resource, args) } }

      private

      def process(resource, *args)
        parse(client.send(resource, ids(resource, args)))
      end

      def ids(resource, *args)
        args.each_with_object([]) do |arg,a|
          case arg
          when Hash
            v = arg['links'][resource.to_s]
            v.each { |e| a << e } unless v.nil?
          when Numeric
            a << arg
          when String
            a << arg unless [:accounts, :contacts].include?(resource)
          end
        end
      end

      def client
        Foo::Client
      end

      def parse(json)
        Foo::Adapter::JSON.parse(json)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Examples**

Actually, I am not 100% certain this is working, because I am not familiar with JSON, but I expect it will not be difficult to repair if there are errors.

I did a poor-man's test by commenting-out `private` and running:

```
resource = :accounts
p Foo::Client.ids(resource, 1, 2)
  #=>[1, 2]

resource = :contacts
p Foo::Client.ids(resource, 3, 'jesse-pinkman', 5,
    {'links' => {resource.to_s => [98, 99]}})
  #=> [3, 5, 98, 99]

resource = :clients
p Foo::Client.ids(resource, 2,'saul-goodman', 6)
  #=> [2, 6, 'saul-goodman']

resource = :services
p Foo::Client.ids(resource, 3, 'saul-goodman', 5,
    {'links' => {resource.to_s => [202, 234]}})
  #=> [202, 234, 3, 5, 'saul-goodman']
```

**Explanation and observations**

- Where is your `Client` class?  I assume from the spec that it is to be defined in the module `Foo`, rather than `Client` including `Foo`, but that's a detail.  Also, you forgot `require 'json'`.  That's obvious, but it's still a good idea to include all `require`s when showing your code.
- I didn't know if you intended to include non-positive numeric values, or that you expect them all to be positive and was using `arg.to_i > 0` to distinguish them from strings.  If you want to exclude non-positive Fixnums, add `if arg > 0` in the appropriate place.
- You will recall that `case` statements use [Object#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) rather than `==` for determining true and false, which is why, for example, `when Hash` works.
- I don't think you actually need your `client` method, as `self` should be `Foo::Client` whenever `parse(send(resource, ids(resource, args)))` is invoked.
- Rather than using `define_method` to create four class methods, you could simply make my method `process` public and pass the resource as an additional argument; for example: `Foo::Client.process(:accounts, 1, 2)`.  Not advocating, just mentioning.

Comment: Good suggestions. I think your ids method might have too many levels of abstractions however. What do you think? I have a preference for short methods that do only one thing.